# Is there a way to hash passwords directly in MySQL that is compatible with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, hash, password-hash

Basically title, I've been tasked with creating a login system for a website, however they want an administrator to create the credentials given who should and shouldn't be accessing the locked parts of the website. I am aware of using `PASSWORD()` in `MySQL` and `password_hash()/password_verify()` in `PHP` but the two systems do not hash the same way and therefore can not be used together. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this securely and in a way that's easy to use (as some administrators are not very familiar with this type of coding I would like the input system to remain as simple as possible)? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Using `PASSWORD()` in `MySQL` to hash and `password_verify()` in `PHP` to unhash for password verification. I was expecting this to work but apparently they use different hashing systems to the decryption is not correct and a login error is returned instead of a successful login when the user's correct password is entered.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you use `password_hash()` in the administrator tool?

Comment: Apart from the incompatible output, [the documentation for the MySQL `PASSWORD()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) states that it is a) not intended for use in your own applications; and b) removed in MySQL 8.0

Comment: On this note ^ you probably want to be using MySQL 8.

Comment: `however they want an administrator to create the credentials`...OK, so provide a php script where they can submit a form to do this. Then you can use php password functions for the hashing. Admins shouldn't be cresting records directly in the database anyway except as a last resort. They are not immune to making validation errors or violating business rules, which a script can help to enforce.

Comment: `password_verify() in PHP to decrypt `...as an aside, this is technically not correct. Hashing is not the same as encryption, and hashes cannot be decrypted or reversed. Instead, the function uses what it knows about the hash to see if the raw text entered would result in the same hash or not. So it's really a comparison process

Comment: You could alternatively use a SAML solution, so you're not responsible for the passwords at all. For example, this tutorial: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php

Comment: `and password_verify() in PHP to unhash` - `they use different hashing systems to the decryption is not correct` - I highly encourage you to read up on the difference between hashing and encryption and how they work before you continue working on something as sensitive as an authentication system.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL doesn't have any bcrypt functions, so you basically can't.

This sort of verification *should* be done in the application layer. Testing passwords with `password_verify()` is punishingly slow *by design*, this is a key security feature of bcrypt.

If you could do this in the database, you'd be imposing significant load on what is often a critical shared resource. It's easy to scale up application servers, you often just add more, but adding more database servers is highly non-trivial.

I'm not sure why you'd need a database-level password validation function as this should be, exclusively, the concern of your application layer.

Remember, there are *many* different password hashing systems out there, and some are downright awful. MySQL's older hashing method is really not all that difficult crack, which is probably why the intent is to make it inconvenient to use in application code because it's not appropriate for that use.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that they don't want a registration component on the website, they want the admin to make the credentials themselves as only a few people will need credentials.

Comment: @DadijoPenguinez That doesn't negate at all that that the application layer should handle it. That doesn't mean it has to be a registration component. Though I would say having admins make the credentials is also bad practice. You could simply automatically generate passwords instead if you really don't want users to set them for some reason, which is more secure. _Admins shouldn't know users passwords either, only the user themselves should_.

Comment: So... you build something into the application that allows administrators to create accounts... access to that piece within the application is restricted in some way, auth-walled or something. The people who have access to that piece may have accounts already created... build a one-off PHP script that inserts accounts into the database with a password... this is one way to do it, but it's not a great way... passwordless auth for administrators would be better... passwordless auth in general would probably be better...

Comment: @DadijoPenguinez None of us  said anything about a registration component. As the above comments say, you can have an area of the site which is locked down to admins only, and has a page where they can create users.

Comment: Remember here you can write a simple PHP script that assigns a random password to a user and run it via the CLI, though taking that function and putting it in the admin front-end is usually only incrementally more work. It's an application layer problem. Don't think you can solve this with `INSERT INTO users`. You shouldn't be doing that in the first place.